# Erro 500 ao acessar qualquer página no Joomla 3.x

Tags: php, joomla

Baixei a identidade padrão do governo em Joomla 3.x através do repositório https://github.com/joomlagovbr/joomla-3.x, conclui o desenvolvimento do site e testei em diferentes ambientes, tanto linux quando windows, e ambos pareciam rodar Ok, mas ao hospedar a aplicação, todas as páginas me retornaram erro 500, e não consegui acesso ao site, tentei mudar os dados do meu .htaccess como tal:

```
 ## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
 # Options +FollowSymlinks
```

e também:

```
RewriteBase /
```

Verifiquei se as variáveis do banco de dados estavam corretas, e os endereços de log, e tudo parece estar ok, o que mais pode ser feito para corrigir?

Comment: Ligue para o suporte do seu servidor de hospedagem, pode ser que caiu lá, erros 5xx são erros do servidor. Não aparece mais nenhuma mensagem na tela?

Comment: Nenhuma mensagem aparece na tela, ou na pasta de logs

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema, como foi resolvido?